# How to start and stop Gazebo 1.9?

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9, gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello.

This is a serious question. I faced very strong issues with Gazebo and I just find a way to manage them. This was related to the way I start and stop Gazebo (from ROS in my configuration).

So:

- stop from the Gui, using close window, unable to restart Gazebo properly afterwards. Gazebo should be closed using Ctrl+C from the console which started it (even if it is OK to do that within rviz)
- AND click reset before aborting the main process

My questions are therefore:

- what are the best practice for start/stop
- is there a way to reset automatically the simulation

Thx in advance for your answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3881/how-to-start-and-stop-gazebo-1.9?/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ArnO,

This is a serious answer. With gazebo_ros_pkgs I believe the only way to fully shutdown Gazebo is to Ctrl-C on the command line, closing the Gazebo GUI will not end gzserver.

Although we've worked hard to prevent Gazebo from hanging during shutdown when used with ROS, it does appear there are still some gazbeo-ROS plugins that can occasionally hang. There is still an inconsistency in the way different plugins initialize ROS nodes, node handles, and do message passing that needs to be sorted out - we welcome any bug fixes you have!

Until then, on occasion when gzserver does not properly shutdown with ROS, I have this nice little alias in my .bashrc:

```
alias killgazebo="killall -9 gazebo & killall -9 gzserver  & killall -9 gzclient"
```

Thx for your question.

---

Originally posted by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) with karma: 369 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [micpalmia](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/473/micpalmia/) on 2013-09-05**:
The killgazebo command is wonderful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can stop simulation by pressing Ctrl-C on the command line, or closing the Gazebo GUI (if you are using the GUI).

In the Gazebo GUI, use Edit->Reset to reset the simulation.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2